# Is it possible to parse min and max functions?

Tags: math.net, mathdotnet-symbolics

As per title, is it possible to parse and evaluate the min and max functions?

As example:

```cs
Expression e = Infix.ParseOrThrow("min(L,B)");
```

It throws:
[image]

Comment: For those who reach here and wish for help: Check out the strategy utilized by OP [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67309376/1118082)